# How can I save memory and speed up while calculating the norm of pandas dataframe rows?

Tags: dataframe, performance, for-loop, memory, calculation

I am trying to calculate the norm between the rows from a dataframe with 1000 rows and the rows from a dataframe with 100000 rows.

```
list_0 = []
for i in range(len(df_1000)):
    list_1 = []
    for j in range(len(df_100000)):
        list_1.append(linalg.norm(df_1000.iloc[i]-df_100000.iloc[j])
    list_0.append(list_1.index(min(list_1)))
```

I have a 16 GB RAM and currently while running this code I run into memory problems altough I do not see why this is happening since the list list_1 is getting freshly instanced. So I am only saving the values in list_0 and this list will contain 1000 values at max.
Any suggestions and tips are highly appreciated.